# System.Threading.Thread is not supported in Windows 8 Store app

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-store-apps

Windows 8 Store app does not support Thread anymore:

I create a thread in class library:

```
protected static Thread m_thread = null;
```

Then in one of the functions:

```
m_thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunDetection));
m_thread.Start(Something);
```

I also need to abort the function:

```
m_thread.Abort();
```

How can I do this in a WIN8 store app?

Comment: You shouldn't be aborting threads, ever, in any type of environment.

Comment: Access to `System.Threading` namespace is all gone for Windows Store Apps to enforce async APIs for literally every I/O or Network bound tasks. Now thread-pool threads (via TPL or `Threadpool` class which has been introduced in `Windows.System.Threading` namespace) are the only way to queue a work asynchronously which doesn't have to run on main application thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run your thread procedure on the threadpool.

- [Using the thread pool in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465290)
- [ThreadPool class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpool)

Aborting a thread has never been a viable option, as it could hang your entire process (abandoned lock, inconsistent global state).

Answer (score 0):

Creating threads manually usually is a bad practice. You should really deeply understand multithreading to gain advantage. Consider to use [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpool):

```cs
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => { RunDetection(); });
```

Also, use asynchronous methods whenever is possible. I.e. `SomeActionAsync`, `BeginSomeAction`, etc. If class doesn't implement asynchronous methods, than use `ThreadPool` for running synchronous methods.

Comment: "Usually bad practice" - Disagree; just because you need to have a good understanding of something does not mean using it is bad practice.

Comment: That's why I wrote "usually", not "always". In 90% of cases using threads directly would be at least less effective than using other asynchronous techniques. If you need to work with I/O - please use asynchronous methods which supports I/O completion ports, if you need to run some small operation asynchronously - please use ThreadPool, if you need to run some long operation - please use BackgroundWorker, if you need to proceed some heavy calculations - please use `Tasks Parallel Library` which will involve all CPU cores. You must have really specific task to use threads directly.